# Boolean algebra proof (a+b) (a+c)' = a'bc'

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have to prove that (a+b) (a+c)' = a'bc'

My algebra skills are really rusty and I was wondering what identities are used to solve this so I can get a better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use De Morgen's law on $(a+c)'$, and then distribute and over or. One of the resulting terms should vanish.

Comment: Okay I got (a + b) (a' * c') using DeMorgan's law and then a'bc' by using distribution does that look right?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you justify why you can remove the $aa'c'$ term.

Comment: Is it contradiction?

Comment: Yes, you probably have some identity that tells you $aa'$ is false, and then you need to know how false and's and or's with boolean variables.

Comment: Would you mind just walking me through the distribution? I think it would be (a*a'*c) + (a'bc')

Comment: Yes, that's right.